# Kubernetes: AKS Ingress only communicates with Pods on same node and subnet

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a 3-node AKS kubernetes cluster deployed (kubenet is the networking overlay), with NGINX Ingress configured to do name-based routing to pods.

I have a number of identical applications deployed under different names on the cluster.

I can reach some applications via http, but not others. On close inspection, I see the applications that I can reach are all on the same node as the ingress controller and same internal 172.* subnet.

All the applications are in the same namespace as the ingress controller.

The unreachable applications are all on the other 2 nodes and different subnets. So it appears this is a networking configuration problem.

However, I cannot find what relevant configuration would allow the ingress to reach all applications regardless of which node and internal subnet they;re on. This, I believe, should be the default behaviour of Kubernetes.

How would I configure this desired behaviour?

Some test results:

```
 kubectl logs https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-7ljkb  --namespace ingress-nginx --follow
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:    0.23.0
  Build:      git-be1329b22
  Repository: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

W0611 14:37:06.679648       6 flags.go:213] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false)
nginx version: nginx/1.15.9
W0611 14:37:06.685012       6 client_config.go:549] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0611 14:37:06.685884       6 main.go:200] Creating API client for https://172.17.0.1:443
I0611 14:37:06.712278       6 main.go:244] Running in Kubernetes cluster version v1.14 (v1.14.0) - git (clean) commit 641856db18352033a0d96dbc99153fa3b27298e5 - platform linux/amd64
I0611 14:37:07.055688       6 nginx.go:261] Starting NGINX Ingress controller
I0611 14:37:07.066491       6 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"tcp-services", UID:"56d2e0c2-8c47-11e9-8911-8272a7251f4e", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"5775", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/tcp-services
I0611 14:37:07.067855       6 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"nginx-configuration", UID:"56cdccf4-8c47-11e9-8911-8272a7251f4e", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"5774", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/nginx-configuration
I0611 14:37:07.075165       6 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"udp-services", UID:"56d6c9e3-8c47-11e9-8911-8272a7251f4e", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"5776", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/udp-services
I0611 14:37:08.159406       6 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"https-ingress", UID:"103260ed-8c4a-11e9-8911-8272a7251f4e", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"17054", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress ingress-nginx/https-ingress
I0611 14:37:08.160481       6 backend_ssl.go:68] Adding Secret "ingress-nginx/chachingtls" to the local store
I0611 14:37:08.256541       6 nginx.go:282] Starting NGINX process
I0611 14:37:08.256572       6 leaderelection.go:205] attempting to acquire leader lease  ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
I0611 14:37:08.257345       6 controller.go:172] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0611 14:37:08.261914       6 status.go:148] new leader elected: nginx-ingress-controller-6674b5b5dc-nhjcc
I0611 14:37:08.328794       6 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"https-ingress", UID:"103260ed-8c4a-11e9-8911-8272a7251f4e", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"17059", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress ingress-nginx/https-ingress
I0611 14:37:08.391940       6 controller.go:190] Backend successfully reloaded.
I0611 14:37:08.392044       6 controller.go:200] Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second.
[11/Jun/2019:14:37:09 +0000]TCP200000.000
```

- List of application pods in same namespace:

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
durian                                      1/1     Running   0          12m   172.18.0.14   aks-agentpool-82039614-0   <none>           <none>
https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-mg7lm   1/1     Running   0          15m   172.18.2.11   aks-agentpool-82039614-2   <none>           <none>
kiwi                                        1/1     Running   0          12m   172.18.2.14   aks-agentpool-82039614-2   <none>           <none>
mango                                       1/1     Running   0          13m   172.18.2.12   aks-agentpool-82039614-2   <none>           <none>
mangosteen                                  1/1     Running   0          12m   172.18.2.13   aks-agentpool-82039614-2   <none>           <none>
orange                                      1/1     Running   0          12m   172.18.2.15   aks-agentpool-82039614-2   <none>           <none>
```

- different internal network and node: timeout:

```
kubectl exec -ti https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-mg7lm  /bin/bash -n ingress-nginx
www-data@https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-7ljkb:/etc/nginx$
www-data@https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-7ljkb:/etc/nginx$
www-data@https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-7ljkb:/etc/nginx$ curl http://172.18.1.10:5678
^C
```

- same internal network and node - OK:

```
www-data@https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-7ljkb:/etc/nginx$
www-data@https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-7ljkb:/etc/nginx$
www-data@https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-7ljkb:/etc/nginx$ curl http://172.18.2.9:5679
mango
```

- same internal network and node - OK:

```
www-data@https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-7ljkb:/etc/nginx$ curl http://172.18.2.5:8080
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css" >
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <style>
      html
```

- different internal network/node - timeout:

```
www-data@https-ingress-controller-6bc79d6c69-7ljkb:/etc/nginx$ curl http://172.18.1.9:5678

^C
```

I've destroyed and re-deployed the cluster and applications a number of times with the exact same configuration and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: How do you configure the vnet and subnet for the AKS cluster? How do you set the nodes in the different subnets?

Comment: There is just one azure subnet in use for this cluster. the vnet is a standard vnet with default configurations. The networking overlay chosen for the cluster is basic "kubenet".

Comment: Have you tried removing and adding the node? This is mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/592#issuecomment-472369700)

Comment: With the basic network "kubelet", the route just works for the nodes and pods also can communicate with each other inside the cluster. You can check the route table in the resource group if there routes for the nodes.

Comment: apparently some routes need to be created to allow different nodes to communicate with each other across their different subnet ranges. I assumed AKs would take care of this automatically. Looking for information on how to do this.

Comment: Any more update for the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in the case of the kubenet networking model, when using pre-existing VNET and subnet (not dedicated to AKS) the routing table with UDRs for the AKS nodes is not attached to the subnet the nodes are deployed to by default, which means that the pods have no way to reach each other across nodes.

The fact that UDRs need to be configured for kubenet is mentioned in the Microsoft Azure documentation, however no instructions are provided on actual setup of routing tables and UDR for AKS.

One has to create these routes after attaching the routing table to the AKS subnet, or add routes to the existing routing table of the subnet (if one exists).

The solution is documented here, it basically involves attaching the default route table generated by the AKS installation to the AKS subnet:

https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/tutorials/custom-vnet.md

i.e, customise and run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rt=$(az network route-table list -g RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME_KUBE -o json | jq -r '.[].id')
az network vnet subnet update \
-g RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME_VNET \
--route-table $rt \
--ids "/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME_VNET/providers/Microsoft.Network/VirtualNetworks/KUBERNETES_CUSTOM_VNET/subnets/KUBERNETES_SUBNET"
```

I'm now able to reach pods on all nodes of the cluster via the Ingress.

NOTE: Alternatively, one could manually add the UDRs to whatever pre-existing routing table you could have attached to the pre-created AKS subnet prior to the AKS deployment.

Answer (score 1):

For the kubelet network in AKS, the pods can communicate with each other. You see the description below:

> With kubenet, nodes get an IP address from the Azure virtual network
>   subnet. Pods receive an IP address from a logically different address
>   space to the Azure virtual network subnet of the nodes. Network
>   address translation (NAT) is then configured so that the pods can
>   reach resources on the Azure virtual network. The source IP address of
>   the traffic is NAT'd to the node's primary IP address.

The pods can communicate with others go through the node with NAT. And only the nodes can receive a routable IP address. You can see the routes in the portal like this:

[image]

And Azure will do all the things for you. It works well in my side. So if it does not work for you. Then you can take a check if the routes are alright.

Here is the screenshot that test the communicate for the pods in different address space:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @charles - Basically I found that the basic AKS installation did not associate the routing table it creates to the subnet. My guess is probably because the subnet is pre-existing with a routing table. My answer posted below.

Comment: @TraianoWelcome It's the possible reason. And it recommends that create the AKS cluster with a new vnet or a new subnet in the existing vnet. Maybe you can mark my answer while it guides you in the right direction for the problem.